# How to set a conditional based on multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, notifications, conditional-statements

**notifications/index** has `<%= render partial: "notifications/notification", collection: @notifications %>`, which contains:

```
<% if Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id) == @habit %>
  <%= link_to "your habit", habit_path(notification) %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "your value", valuation_path(notification) %>
<% end %>
```

which shows gives the error for the 1st line:

> Couldn't find Habit with 'id'=

even though the **console** shows:

```
pry(main)> Comment.find(1)
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Comment:0x007f86201267b0
 id: 1,
 content: "test",
 goal_id: nil,
 habit_id: 1,
 valuation_id: nil,
 quantified_id: nil,
 commentable_id: nil,
 commentable_type: nil,
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 00:07:22 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 04:04:29 UTC +00:00,
```

How can we use a conditional so that each notification is pointing to the right path?

**notifications_controller**

```
def index
  @habit = Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
  @notifications = current_user.notifications
  @notifications.each do |notification|
    notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
  end
end
```

The notifications are based on if a user comments on a habit or value:

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

private

  def create_notification
      Notification.create(
       user_id: self.user_id,
       comment_id: self.id,
       read: false
      )
  end
end
```

I followed this notifications tutorial but it is based on using just one model: http://evanamccullough.com/2014/11/ruby-on-rails-simple-notifications-system-tutorial/

**comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :like]

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Comment was updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment destroyed."
  end

  def like
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
      @comment.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Too many likes'
    end  
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = find_commentable
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  # add more commentable models here
  def find_commentable
    if params[:goal_id]
      Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
    elsif params[:habit_id]
      Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    elsif params[:valuation_id]
      Valuation.find(params[:valuation_id])
    elsif params[:quantified_id]
      Quantified.find(params[:quantified_id])
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
  end
end
```

Comment: What are your params?

Comment: There is none @test It wasn't in the tutorial I did. Is that something that would be needed now?

Comment: So in index method your @habit must be nil...right....?

Comment: Yea it gives the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Habit with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/notifications_controller.rb:3:in 'index'` with `[["id", nil]]`

Comment: From whenever you are calling index method of notification,you should send habit_id and your error will be resolved

Comment: <%= link_to 'Notifications', notifications_path (:habit_id => @habit.id) %>

Comment: Sorry how does this solve it? You lost me here a little bit @test

Comment: How you are calling index method of notifications.?

Comment: In the index I have the line `<%= render partial: "notifications/notification", collection: @notifications %>`

Comment: I am asking how you are calling index method?

Comment: Umm sorry I'm confused. notifications/index.html.erb is automatically called by the notifications_controller @test

Comment: I pretty much followed the tutorial I had mentioned to the t with the exception of a few things shown in the question @test Idk if looking their would clarify what my stupidity may not be able to identify

Comment: There must be a link that is calling notification index

Comment: @test I'm calling index method of notifications via  `collection: @notifications` in the index to the controller def index `@notifications.each do |notification|
     notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
   end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, according with MVC, you shouldn't make SQL queries in the view's:

`<% if Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id) == Habit.find(params[:habit_id]) %>`
bad practice!

You should make the Query in the controller and then using the instance variable of the controller(the variable with the @) in the view.

Second, `params[:habit_id]` will only work if your url has the param ´habit_id' something like: `?habit_id=[id]`
but since your view shouldn't make any queries, you should change that first.

Comment: Thank you! I just put it in the view for the question. Won't do that again :) To your second point, can you elaborate on what I did wrong? Should I add a params to notifications with `:habit` in it somehow?

Comment: what is the url to go to that view?

Comment: I haven't completely figured that out yet. I wanted to get the conditional to work first, but for now I put `habit_path(notification)` and `valuation_path(notification)` which leads to for the former: http://0.0.0.0:3000/habits/9 but that is wrong because their is no habit with that id. Like I said I need to eventually figure out how to fix this :/